# I want to have an action to all of a treeview's nodes

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I have a windows application in c# with a tree view .now i want to check all nodes of that tree view including node's of nodes .
i tried this code  :

```
for (int i = 0; i < treevwaccess.Nodes.Count; i++)
{                
    formid = treevwaccess.Nodes[i].Name;
    access = treevwaccess.Nodes[i].Checked;
    user.updateaccesslevel(lblId.Text, formid, access);
}
```

but this code only check nodes in level 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either a `Stack` or a recursive method like this:

```
DoStuff(treevwaccess.Nodes);

...

void DoStuff(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        user.updateaccesslevel(lblId.Text, node.Name, node.Checked);
        DoStuff(node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and call recursive function like this

```
static void main()
{
    var treevwaccess = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
    CheckAll(treevwaccess.Nodes);
}

static void CheckAll(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection nodes )
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        var formid = node.Name;
        var access = node.Checked;
        user.updateaccesslevel(lblId.Text, formid, access);
        CheckAll(node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check child node of root node too.

For that please try this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < treevwaccess.Nodes.Count; i++)
{ 
      formid = treevwaccess.Nodes[i].Name;
      access = treevwaccess.Nodes[i].Checked;
      user.updateaccesslevel(lblId.Text, formid, access);
      CheckChildNodes(treevwaccess.Nodes[i]);
}

void CheckChildNodes(TreeNode node)
{
      if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < node.Nodes.Count; i++)
          {
              formid = node.Nodes[i].Name;
              access = node.Nodes[i].Checked;
              user.updateaccesslevel(lblId.Text, formid, access);
          }
       }
}
```

This will help you.